# how to manipulate attachments using API V4 in CiviCRM 5.60

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-entity

So I am kinda new to civiCRM, I am using the API v4 and creating cases with it.
but I have two questions about the attachments. the attachments are linked to the activity and the activity is linked to the case. so in order to get the attachements we need to get throw all those tables.

*PS: attachments are referred as File in the api explorer.*

in the API V4 explorer, we notice that we need a join in order to link the activity and case and for that we have an entity bridge called caseActivity it works just fine.
but for the File and Activity entities we don't have an entity bridge like caseActivity.
so my question is how can we link between Activity and File entities knowing that we have a SQL table called civicrm_entity_file that has the data we need for the join.

[image]

so the final goal is to get a case based on it's ID and get the attachments and the activity.

Another question I have : how to do the upload (File) using the API v4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an ongoing discussion at chat.civicrm.org and also at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25845. Short answer is it's not implemented yet.